# Trying to toggle this jQuery menu at 2 different screen sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm working on this navigation, and I've got code for how it works on two different screen sizes. 600px and below, and then anything over 600px. Each menu works fine independently at each size, but I can't seem to get them menus to go back and forth, like if you were to play with the menu at regular size, shrink your screen, play with the menu at the smaller size, and then try to expand your menu again, the menu doesn't re-expand the way it should. At first I thought it was because I was using the jQuery `toggle()`, so I changed it to an `if/else` function that messes with the targeted class' CSS display. But the display for the menu still wont revert to block when the screen expands. Am I overlooking something?

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0fcm6ey/).

**jQuery (code in question)**

```
$("#menu-icon").click(function(){

            if ( $(".menu-item").css("display") == "none" ) {
                $(".menu-item").css("display", "block");
            } 
            else if ( $(".menu-item").css("display") == "block" ) {
                $(".menu-item").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
```

**CSS (code in question)**

```
menu-item {
display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

menu-item {
display: none;
}

}
```

I don't think the HTML is causing this, but it's included in the jsFiddle in it entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the logic. If the small menu is showing and the user clicks the menu button, you hide the items to "close the menu" which is fine if the small menu is showing. But then, if you make the window bigger, nothing has clicked the menu button to "show the menu" so the elements are still hidden.

You could bind a function to the window resize event and check the window width and if it's over 600px force the app to re-show the items. This would ensure that no matter what state the small menu is in, if the window gets bigger, the items are visible:

#### [Working jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0fcm6ey/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var $window = $(window);
    var $items = $(".menu-item");
        
    $("#menu-icon").click(function(){
        $items.toggle();
    });
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize > 600) {
            //if the window is greater than 600px wide then turn on jScrollPane..
            $items.show();
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $window.resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Comment: YAY! It works perfectly! Thank you! I'm very new to jQuery so while I suspected I could link the behavior to the screen resizing, I had no idea how to go about doing it. Thank you so much!